# How to mock protected final method of base class using jmockit

Tags: jmockit

```
public class Dao1 extends GenericDao{
}

public class Dao2 extends Dao1{
}

public class GenericDao(){

    protected final Session getCurrentSession() {
    LOG.debug("getting current Session");
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

I am testing methods in `Dao2` and wants to mock `getCurrentSession` method from `GenericDao`.

I tried to mock it using

```
new MockUp<GenericDao>() {
        @Mock
         protected Session getCurrentSession() {
            return session;
        }
    };
}
```

I am getting following exception at line `new MockUp<GenericDao>()`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader: method <init>()V not found
at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.verifyInitialization(Startup.java:172)
at mockit.MockUp.<clinit>(MockUp.java:94)
```

Comment: Maybe you would rather mock `sessionFactory` dependency and `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession` method?

Comment: @Felix I tried to Mock `sessionFactory` and Wrote `Expectation` block for `getCurrentSession` method. I am getting the same exception. Is it due to protected, final method or Can it be IDE jar issue?

Comment: It certainly has nothing to do with `getCurrentSession()` being `final` (for JMockit, this makes no difference). The error points to a no-args constructor, but I have no idea why... perhaps with a complete test which reproduces the error?

Comment: Make sure you only have one version of the jmockit library in the classpath... as the stack trace seems to indicate a class version issue.